# React drop zone for both files and draggable elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

Is there available a React drop zone component that accepts both files and draggable React elements?

I've used [react-dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/), which is great for files, but in addition to that, I'd like to be able to drag UI elements onto the same zone, where the same kind of data (JSON) would come in from a [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) object.